# Password correct but error message saying its incorrect

Tags: php

I can't figure out what is wrong with program. The password I know is correct but for some reason I am receiving an error saying it is incorrect.

here is my signup.php

```
$UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$msd5Password = $md5[$password];
$email = $_POST['email'];


if ($UserName == null || $password == null || $email == null) {
echo 'Please Fill In All The Values';
}
else {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '$email'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($numrows !=0)
{
die("There already is an account created with the email you entered.");
}
else
{
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die (mysql_error);
mysql_select_db ("thereview");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO login (UserName, password, email) VALUES       ('$UserName', '$md5Password', '$email')")
or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:login.php");
 }
}
```

And here is my login.php

```
session_start();
$UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($UserName == null|| $password == null) {
echo 'Please fill in UserName and Password';
}
else{
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die (mysql_error);
mysql_select_db ("thereview");
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM login WHERE UserName = '$UserName'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows != 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$dbEmail = $row['email'];
$dbUserName = $row['UserName'];
$dbPassword = $row['password'];
$dbId = $row['id'];
}
if($UserName = $dbUserName && md5($password) == $dbPassword) {
$_SESSION['UserName'] = $dbUserName;
$_SESSION['email'] = $dbEmail;
}
else {
echo 'UserName or Password is incorrect';
}
}
else {
echo 'User does not exist, Create an Account';
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, your code is massively open to **SQL INJECTION**

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injections. You should read about that.

Comment: Thanks rdlowrey and Truth i figured it would be lol, I just wanted to get it working first then go back and fix it up secruity wise. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo here:

```
$msd5Password = $md5[$password];
```

should probably be:

```
$md5Password = md5($password);
```

Keep in mind MD5 is not good for password security any longer and you have VERY POOR security for this script, open to injection and other issues.

Comment: Yes i was reading up on sql injection and am finding that md5 is no longer valid option. I will read up on how to secure this better. Thanks for helping me out Jakub

Comment: hey Jakub i made those changes but no it is saying error undefined index line 20, here is my code for line 20 $dbPassword = $row['password']; do you see anything wrong with this

Comment: seems like `$row['password']` is undefined. (coming from your db i am guessing).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about this?

```
$msd5Password = $md5[$password];
```

I think it should be:

```
$md5Password = md5($password);
```

Comment: You mean it should be `md5($password)` (not `$md5`)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($UserName **=** $dbUserName && md5($password) == $dbPassword)
```

will always give you false...

Try `$UserName **==** $dbUserName` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I tried this, but since pre didnt accept the bold markup, I left it.

Answer (score 0):

- `$msd5Password = $md5[$password];` should probably read: `$md5Password = md5($password);` (careful about the details - dollars and parenthesis)
- `$UserName = $dbUserName` should probably be `$UserName == $dbUserName`

Comment: Thanks for catching that gfish

Answer (score 0):

In the sign up script you write $md5$password

I'm not strong in php, but shouldn't that be md5($password) as you write in the login script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You need to put parenthesis around these commands to make sure that its a test of only those values.  Also where you have $UserName = $dbUserName you need to have it be == instead of =.  Otherwise it will always be set to true rather then be testing it.

```
if(($UserName == $dbUserName) && (md5($password) == $dbPassword))
```

Also, at the top the code you have is this:

```
$msd5Password = $md5[$password];
```

You have two typos in there.  First of all your variable later on is md5Password so you need to remove the s.  Also the syntax for md5 is md5($password). Finally md5 is a function not a variable so you don't need the $.

Correct Syntax:

```
$md5Password = md5($password);
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Trent both those corrections were very helpful but for some reason it is still saying undefined index line 20, here is my code for line 20 $dbPassword = $row['password'];    do you see anything wrong with this

Comment: Try taking your $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); out of the while loop and getting rid of the loop.  Since your only fetching one record I don't think you require the loop.  I'm looking but I don't see any other errors.

Comment: Also, if you would post the entire error message that would be helpful!

Comment: sorry for not posting the entire error, but your suggestions worked, thanks again Trent

Comment: Not a problem.  Hope I can help in the future!